# Hashed password recovery

Tags: c#, hash, passwords, password-recovery

I'm currently coding using mvc 5 template. The password is currently hashed. I want to recover this password so I can email it if the person has forgotten his/her password. 
Any tips on hashed password recovery?

Comment: ***NO NO NO***.  You ***can't*** recover a hashed password - that's the whole point! And you should ***NEVER*** email a password anyway!  Give the user a password reset link.  Sigh, this is 2015 - there are plenty of resources that explain how to do things like this the right way - when are people going to get it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password Recovery without sending password via email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041181/password-recovery-without-sending-password-via-email)

Comment: Did you saw [this](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity)?

Answer (score 4):

**Your approach is fundamentally wrong!**

A hashed password can't easily be "unhashed", as that is the whole point of a hash. Take, for example, the sum of a digit in math:
`435 -> 4+3+5 = 12`

Here, `435` would be the password and `12` would be the hash. Hashing the same number this way will give the same result every time. However, you can not go backwards, as 12 could've been made up from other combinations as well (`9+3`, `2+2+2+2+2+2`, ...).

You could use rainbow tables, but then you would be trying to hack yourself. That's definitely **not** what you want to do. What you **want** to do instead is to give the user a way to reset their password. Send them a link where they can do just that.

Comment: Reset should be a better option. Thanks mate

Comment: Ravz, consider marking this answer as *accepted* (tick mark). Alternatively you could also provide your own answer, then mark that as accepted. Worst case, you could even delete your question. Point is, your question is currently still *open*; it would be nice if we could mark it as *solved* or otherwise get it out of Stack Overflow's pipeline.